# Is it safe to store User ID within the Flask session?

Tags: python, flask, session-cookies

I have found a number of articles online explaining that the Flask session is *secured* and not *encrypted*.

This means that users can Base64 decode the cookie and read the values inside.

Is it an issue if my application uses the User ID value from this session cookie to authenticate the user after he successfully logs in?

If I understand correctly, the user will not be able to change his cookie value to an ID of another user, as it signed by the application private key on the server side. Is that correct?

And if so, are there any issues with using the *secured* contents of the Flask cookie-based session to allow users access to protected views of the application?

Comment: It is okay to use cookie-based sessions, although you should use HTTPS to avoid some man in the middle to steal the cookie and access the session (but that goes for any kind of web service or application with authorized access anyway). Also the cookies should be [HttpOnly](https://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/) to avoid some XSS cookie stealing (I think Flask do this automatically for session cookies).

Comment: @jdehesa thank you! Have found an interesting blog about this: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/cookie-security-for-flask-applications

Comment: So just to confirm - there is no way for the attacker to forge the session data? Because in case of my app that would enable them to present themselves as a different user to the API

Comment: If your session cookies are signed, then they cannot be forged, no (that is, unless your signing key is stolen, but by then you would probably have far worse problems). That's the whole point of cookie signing. You can also encrypt the contents of the cookie so user ids themselves are not visible to end users, or better yet not use user ids at all in the cookies but only session ids (associated to users in the backend).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarise answers given in the comments:

- Cookie can be tampered with but if Flask session security is enabled, such tampered session will be [thrown away](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/cookie-security-for-flask-applications), forcing the client to re-login
- The session data Base64-encoded within the cookie can be quite easily viewed. Therefore anything that your clients are not supposed to see should not be included there